# Having trouble with returning fixed-size arrays

Tags: solidity

So I'm having two problems with returning arrays from external functions:

Case One: arrays in getters

```
contract A {
  mapping(address => uint8[10]) public gameBoards;
}

// test.sol
function testGetGameBoard() {
  address myAddress;
  uint8[10] memory gameBoard = a.boards(address);
  Assert.equal(gameBoard[0], 0, 'uint8 arrays are initialized with 0');
  // TypeError: Member "equal" not unique after argument-dependent lookup in type(library Assert)
```

From [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/19216/compile-error-with-trivial-assertion-in-truffle-test) it looks like the compiler can't infer `gameBoard[0]` is a `uint8`?  I'm not sure what's going on.

Case Two: arrays in structs

```
contract A {
  mapping(address => Game) public games;
  struct Game {
    address player;
    uint8[10] board;
  }
}

// test.sol
function testGetGame() {
  address myAddress;
  var(player, board) = a.games(myAddress);
  // TypeError: Not enough components (1) in value to assign all variables (2).
```

From what I understand, return values need to be known in size, which prevents you from returning dynamic arrays and strings.  But a fixed array `uint8[10]` should be known in size, right?  It's not clear to me why I'm getting both of these errors.  Any explanation as to what's going on would be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't think either of these errors are about dynamic array return values. The first is about memory vs storage, and in any case your variable names don't match. In the second you're trying to read two variables from a function that only returns one.

Comment: Hi @EdmundEdgar, thanks for the reply.  The variables don't match because I'm trying to kludge my code into a format that's more readable.  I've edited it to make the variables match :)

Comment: If you don't mind expanding on the second case, it looks like struct mappings return the destructured struct.  Is that not true?  For example `struct Game { address playerOne; address playerTwo }` allows me to destructure it as `var(addrOne, addr2) = myContract.games(myAddress);`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the size of `uint8[10]` is known. The problem is, there are two types of `uint8[10]`:

```
uint8[10] storage var1;
uint8[10] memory var2;
```

If you create a `uint8[10] memory`, the memory required for the array is dynamically allocated when the contract code starts running. It will be destroyed when the contract execution finishes.

A `uint8[10] storage` is more like a pointer to a `uint8[10]` which is stored in the blockchain as a contract member variable. A `uint8[10] storage` is not an array itself.

It is not possible to directly assign a `uint8[10] memory` to a `uint8[10] storage` pointer.

You should probably read the Solidity manual on this:

http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html#data-location

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Jesse for pointing me in the right direction.  That is helpful.  If you don't mind me asking, what's the correct move here?  It _looks_ ok to have a public mapping of `address => uint8[10]`.

How should I consume it in another contract, e.g. the test?  I'd like to get a particular value from the mapping and be able to access it by index.

`uint8[10] storage gameBoard = a.gameBoards(myAddress);` will create a pointer to an array on the blockchain, right?  So shouldn't I be able to access an element with `[]`?

Comment: I try to assert its value to `0` with `Assert.equal(gameBoard[0], 0, 'uint8 arrays are initialized with 0');` and get the `Assert` library type error I listed above.

Comment: @mzemel It's perfectly OK to have a mapping like that. You need to use square brackets to read from a mapping, just like reading from an array: `a.gameBoards[myAddress]`

Comment: Hm, I was under the impression that public mappings use parens for accessing an element when its external to the contract declaring the mapping.  For example, `a.gameBoards[myAddress]` results in `TypeError: Indexed expression has to be a type, mapping or array (is function (address) external returns (uint8[10] memory))`

I think without the parens it tries to evaluate `a.gameBoards` which is a function, externally, not a mapping.

Comment: @mzemel you are right.
Per public parameter an 'automatic' view function is added. For arrays, this function will take the array index as input parameter.

bun internally the mapping is handled as an array.